# .Net Core 3 AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

Here's how I setup the auto mapper in `startUp.cs`

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddDbContext<BikeStoreContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("bikeStore")));
        services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();

        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(CustomerProfile));

    }
```

The profile.cs

```
   public class CustomerProfile : Profile
    {
        public CustomerProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Customer,CustomerDto>();
            CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>();
        }
    }
```

CustomerDto.cs

```
    public class CustomerDto
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is the `getCustomers` function in my repository

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetCustomers()
    {
        return await _context.Customers.ToListAsync();
    }
```

I use autoMapper in the controller as below

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync ()
    {
        var result = await _repo.GetCustomers();
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<CustomerDto>(result));
    }
```

And I get the below error when trying to map Customer to CustomerDto

```
AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
```

I tried to change the configuration in startUp.cs as below but it didn't work.

```
    var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
        mc.AddProfile(new CustomerProfile());
    });

    IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: And where do you use automapper?

Comment: And `_mapper` is resolved in ctor?

Comment: Yes using dependency injection

Comment: Try `_mapper.Map<List<CustomerDto>>(result)`

Comment: @GuruStron Opps! what a silly mistake so that means whenever I'm returning a list I have to explicitly write it down. Thank you ,Post the answer to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repository returns `IEnumerable<Customer>` and you are trying to map it to single `CustomerDTO`, you need to map to collection, for example `List` or just another `IEnumerable`:

```cs
return Ok(_mapper.Map<List<CustomerDto>>(result));
```